# Combinatoric — selection

Tags: combinatorics, summation

> There are 15 people who are batsmen only and 5 people who are bowlers
> only. There are 3 all-rounders (can bat and bowl). How many ways are
> there to select 4 batsmen and 3 bowlers?

**Attempt:**

The following function calculates the probability for $x$ number of all rounders being selected for batting and $y$ number of all-rounders selected for bowling.

$f(x,y)$ = $15\choose 4-x$ $5\choose 3-y$ $3\choose x$ ${3-x}\choose y$

Summating over all possibilities:

$$\sum_{m = 0}^3 \sum_{n = 0}^m f(n, m - n)$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s right

Comment: With that edit this looks fine.

Comment: At a first glance, to be precise, I wouldn't say the function calculates the probability for $x$ all rounders for batting and $y$ for bowling, but rather the number of ways of selecting $x$ for batting and $y$ for bowling. We would only talk of probability once it has been mentioned specifically, so for instance if we were told that players were somehow selected at random, we might ask what the probability of a given configuration would be. As for your final answer, it seems right.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the function that you have defined

$$ f(x,y)=  {3\choose {x}} {{3-x} \choose {y}} {15 \choose {4-x}} {5\choose {3-y}}  $$

the solution is

$$\sum_{x = 0}^3 \sum_{y = 0}^{3-x} f(x, y)$$